# Windows Phone SDK 8.0 install issue on Windows 8

Tags: windows, sdk, windows-phone-8

I am trying to install the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 on Windows 8 (it's not the PRO edition, it's the edition that came with the laptop when I bought it), but the installation got stuck like in the below picture:

[image]

It's been like this for an hour and I don't what the problem is.

Comment: Is it still like that? Did you try to cancel and reinstall?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not really "stuck".  It is downloading a large install in the background (~1.6GB).  It's probably better to click the ISO image link below the download link to download the disc image first, then mount it and install from there.

I tried the 1MB install file and it took over 5 hours to finish installing, downloading at around 150kb per sec.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I managed to install the sdk only with the ISO image as you suggested. Thanks again :)